# Relating Coin Flip Problem to Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

If we let $X_n$ be the number of heads after flipping a fair coin $n$ times, what is

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bbb P(X_{2n} > n + \sqrt n, X_{4n} > X_{2n} + n - \sqrt n)$?

The hint is to use the convergence of a random walk to Brownian motion, so my initial thoughts were about relating the probabilities to the normal distribution, but I wasn't sure how that relates to the hint, and in any case the scenario doesn't seem to mirror a symmetric random walk, as $X_n$ is just counting the number of heads.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo in the expression: > not ,?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Makes sense to me; $P(A,B)$ means $P(A\cap B$).

Comment: Mike is correct, it means A and B.

Comment: So $A=X_{2n}\gt n+\sqrt{n}$ and $B=X_{4n}\gt X_{2n}+ n-\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Why should you be bothered to use Brownian motion? If I understand correctly $X_{2n}$ and $X_{4n}-X_{2n}$ are independent hence you can decompose your probability in two simpler probabilities, which can be treated easily by the usual CLT.

Comment: Maybe it helps that $2 X_n - n$ is a symmetric random walk.